# Looping through nested arrays using VUEJS

Tags: vuejs2

/*I have the following JSON data. I need to list students doing a particular subject. How can this be done using v-for in VUEJS?*/

```
students_subjects:

    [
         {
         student_id:1,
         student_name:"Moses",
         reg_no:"ABC/2019", 
         subjects:[
                     {
            subject_id:1
            subject_name:"English"      
              },
                     {
            subject_id:2
            subject_name:"Maths"            
              }
                   ]
          },
         {
         student_id:2,
         student_name:"James",
         reg_no:"ABD/2019", 
         subjects:[
                     {
            subject_id:1
            subject_name:"English"      
              },
                     {
            subject_id:2
            subject_name:"Maths"            
              }
                   ]
          }

    ]
```

// My structure of html code is as shown below

```
<div id="app">
        <ul>
           <li v-for="item in students">
              <div class="row " style="background-color: #f4fbee;">
                  <div class="col-md-2">{{item.reg_no}}</div>
             </div>
                 <div class="row" v-for="subjects in item.subjects">{{subjects.subject_name}}
             </div>
        </li>
           </ul>  

<pre>{{students}}</pre>
<p>{{getStudentsBySubjectId}}</p>

</div>
var appVM=new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:function(){    
        return {
            student_id: '',
            reg_no:'',
            student_name:'',
            students:Array(),
            subjects:{},

        }

    },
    created:function (){
        this.getAllStudents();
    },
    methods:{
        getAllStudents:function(){
            var self=this;
              axios.get("/Students/list").then(function (response) {
                    this.students = response.data;

              }.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error while fetching student data: ' + error)
              })
        },
        getStudentsBySubjectId:function (students, subjectId) {
            return students.filter(function(student) {
                return student.subjects.some(function(subject) {
                    return subject.subject_id === subjectId;
                })
            })
        }

    },

})

</script>
```

// How do we get to display the filtered students.
  //The code above shows the data returned on on calling the array on the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using ES6.
Here's how you would find all the students taking a particular subject:

```
function getStudentsBySubjectId(students, subjectId) {
    return students.filter(student => student.subjects.some(subject => subject.subject_id === subjectId))
}
```

For ES5, use normal functions instead of arrow functions:

```
function getStudentsBySubjectId(students, subjectId) {
    return students.filter(function(student) {
        return student.subjects.some(function(subject) {
            return subject.subject_id === subjectId;
        })
    })
}
```

you can simply `v-for` over the array returned by the above function.

Comment: Thanks so much. However I am using ES5. So am getting an error filter not defined. How do we do it in ES5? Regards

Comment: ES5 supports `filter`, it just doesn't support the arrow functions. I've updated my answer for ES5

Comment: Thanks. I have given more details above. Thanks as you find time to respond. @Kumar